# Where clause not working as expected: I get data from 2 different IDs when only one is specified

Tags: mysql, sql, database, mariadb

I have this script:

```
    CREATE TABLE `Usuario` (
    `IDUsuario` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
     PRIMARY KEY (`IDUsuario`)
);

CREATE TABLE `Cliente` (
    `Cedula` VARCHAR(9) NOT NULL,
    `FK_Usuario` INT NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`Cedula`, `FK_Usuario`)
);

CREATE TABLE `NotaCreditoDebito` (
    `IDNota` BIGINT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `FK_Cliente` VARCHAR(9) NOT NULL,
    `FK_Usuario` INT NOT NULL,
    `NoNota` CHAR(2) NOT NULL,
    `Tipo` CHAR(2) NOT NULL,
     PRIMARY KEY (`IDNota`, `FK_Cliente`, `FK_Usuario`)
);

ALTER TABLE `Cliente` ADD FOREIGN KEY (`FK_Usuario`) REFERENCES `Usuario`(`IDUsuario`);
ALTER TABLE `NotaCreditoDebito` ADD FOREIGN KEY (`FK_Usuario`) REFERENCES `Usuario`(`IDUsuario`);
ALTER TABLE `NotaCreditoDebito` ADD FOREIGN KEY (`FK_Cliente`) REFERENCES `Cliente`(`Cedula`);

INSERT INTO Usuario VALUES();

/*Usuario 1 has 2 Clientes*/
INSERT INTO Cliente VALUES('000000000',1);
INSERT INTO Cliente VALUES('123456789',1);

/*Cliente 000000000 has 2 NotaCreditoDebito */
INSERT INTO NotaCreditoDebito VALUES(0,'000000000',1,'N1','01');
INSERT INTO NotaCreditoDebito VALUES(0,'000000000',1,'N2','02');

/*Cliente 123456789 has 1 NotaCreditoDebito */
INSERT INTO NotaCreditoDebito VALUES(0,'123456789',1,'N3','01');
```

When I execute the following query I get data for **both two** `Cliente` even though I only want to get data only for `Cliente` **000000000**. Why is that? What's wrong?

```
SELECT

NCD.IDNota,
NCD.FK_Cliente,
NCD.FK_Usuario,
NCD.NoNota,
NCD.Tipo

FROM NotaCreditoDebito NCD INNER JOIN Usuario U ON NCD.FK_Usuario=U.IDUsuario
                           INNER JOIN Cliente C ON NCD.FK_Cliente=C.Cedula
WHERE NCD.Tipo='01' OR NCD.Tipo='02' AND NCD.FK_Cliente='000000000' AND NCD.FK_Usuario=1;
```

**Query Result**
[image: Query Result]

Comment: You need parentheses when you mix AND and OR, unless you understand precedence (which you don't).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`OR` has lower precedence than `AND`.  Pretty much your where is

```
WHERE NCD.Tipo='01' OR (NCD.Tipo='02' AND NCD.FK_Cliente='000000000' AND NCD.FK_Usuario=1)
```

To resolve, put bracket around your `OR`:

```
WHERE (NCD.Tipo='01' OR NCD.Tipo='02') AND NCD.FK_Cliente='000000000' AND NCD.FK_Usuario=1
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/operator-precedence-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: The link points to documentation for SQL Server but the question is about MySQL and MariaDB (though `AND` precedes `OR` in all of them). [Here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/operator-precedence.html)'s a link for MySQL and [here](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/operator-precedence/) one for MariaDB. And instead of `(NCD.Tipo='01' OR NCD.Tipo='02')` a shortcut of `NCD.Tipo IN ('01', '02')` can be used.